# Heroku Cedar stack and Rails 3.1 RC5 not displaying images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, assets, asset-pipeline

Anyone get Rails 3.1 RC5 running on Heroku, Cedar stack? Everything seems to work so far, except that asset images (such as logo, icons, main_bg, etc.) are not being displayed.

I'm not sure if it is related to this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2299).

Would like to hear from anyone who was able to fix this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tweaking this setting should no longer be necessary in Rails 3.1, but if you're upgrading from earlier versions of 3.1 RC, either comment out the `x_sendfile_header` setting, or set it to `nil` in your `production.rb` file:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil
```

This is the setting recommended in the [Heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#serving_assets_from_your_application).

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. It's worth noting that it's a more obvious fix if you aren't migrating your app (as I was), as the new `production.rb` says to use `X-Accel-Redirect` for nginx.